# Issues with Calculator program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new to Python and I have written my first code to calculate the area of shapes. Each time I run it on Jupyter, it says

> Type Error.

where I got things wrong? (I am using Python 3).

```
# Calculator code for the area of the shape

print("1 rectangle")
print ("2 squared")
print ("3 circle")
shape = input (">> ")

if shape ==1:
   length = input ("What is the length of the rectangle?") 
   breadth = input ("What is the breadth of the rectangle?")
   area = length * breadth *2
   print ("the area of your rectangle", area)

elif shape == 2:
  length = input ("what is the length of one side of the squared")
  area = length *breadth
  print ("the area of your square is ", area)

else shape ==3:
  radius = input ("what is the radius of your circle")
  area = radius *radius*3.14
  print ("area of your circle is ", area)
```

Comment: `input` returns a string. You need to convert your inputs to floats or ints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some things wrong in your code:

1. You have not provided any type to your input. Replace it with `float` for better calculation.
2. You have written the wrong syntax of `else`. See the ***[documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html)***
3. You have calculated the area of square wrongly.

Try below code:

```
print("1 rectangle")
print("2 squared")
print("3 circle")
shape = input (">> ")

if shape == 1:
    length = float(input ("What is the length of the rectangle?"))
    breadth = float(input ("What is the breadth of the rectangle?"))
    area = length * breadth *2
    print ("the area of your rectangle", area)

elif shape == 2:
    length = float(input ("what is the length of one side of the squared"))
    area = length * length
    print ("the area of your square is ", area)

else:
    radius = float(input ("what is the radius of your circle"))
    area = radius *radius*3.14
    print ("area of your circle is ", area)
```

*Hope this answers your question!!!*

Comment: Thanks everyone. The answer provided by #skaul05 worked excellently!